# How to create a FileUpload control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, file-upload

How do I create a Fileupload control in WPF?

I want to upload jpg image files.

Comment: Is this a desktop app? Where are these files getting uploaded to?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're uploading to.  Most likely you'll want to build some sort of service class that takes care of copying the file to the new location.

Then in your XAML you'll have to create a `TextBox` and a `Button` to show a dialog.

Although, you're design options are greatly increased in XAML, so you're not locked into the TextBox - Browse button.  Update your question with more details and I can try to elaborate.

Comment: i want to upload jpg image files Mr.Bendewey

Comment: what are you uploading them to?  FTP, Http Form post? Network Share?  Where is the client running?